# Modifying header css to include text in two different positions

Tags: html, css

I have a header with a link to another page on the left hand side. I need to also put a title in the centre of the header, but don't want to use a navbar. Is this possible? Here is my attempt, which is not working:

html:

```
<div class="header">
    <a href= "#"> Left Side Text </a>
    <p class = "header title">Title Text</p>
</div>
```

css:

```
.header {
    height: auto;
    line-height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 50px;
}


.header .title {
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Qf3w7/

Comment: `<i>` are you actually for real!?

Comment: <i> is used by Font Awesome

Comment: When you say center do you mean centered exactly, without regard for the space that the left side takes up? Or centered in the remaining space?

Comment: `<i>` is till a valid tag although `<em>` is now more common. `<i>` is now used by some for icon fonts etc.

Comment: @AlexThomas some very constructive comments there, thanks

Comment: @MattPileggi centered in the remaining space would probably look best

Comment: @Paulie_D `<em>` is also wrong if not use in the right context.

Comment: @bookthief you're welcome. I wouldn't start worrying about layout, when you have incorrect markup.

Comment: I said that `<em>` has replaced the functionality that `<i`> used to have...nothing more. Everything is wrong if used in the wrong context.

Comment: `<em>` hasn't replaced `<i>` at all. Explain why you think it's replaced it?

Comment: Have now removed the <i> tag given that whether or not it constitutes "good mark up" is completely irrelevant to the question

Comment: @bookthief It may have been irrelevant to the question. But Is it not better to promote good semantics?

Comment: @Alex Thomas Please read what I **actually** wrote. I didn't say they one replaced the other I said that the **functionality**  of the `<i>` has been replaced by `<em>`: http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/i

Comment: @Paulie_D fair play. It annoys me so much when people use the `<em>` and `<strong>` for styling elements italic and bold respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your simple situation I would position your title absolute inside your header and make sure that your link stays on top with `z-index`.

HTML:

```
<div class="header">
    <a href="#" class="link">
        <i class="fa fa-angle-left icon-white arrow"></i> 
        Left Side Text
    </a>
    <div class="title">Title Text</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.link {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1; /* Important, otherwise your link wouldn't be clickable. */
}

.title {
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid green;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/BernhardW/N99jj/).

But please note that in case your title or left-side text get too long, they will overlap each other.

Answer (score 3):

Here is your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vZ9Zu/3/)

You just need a header with:

```
.header {
    height: auto;
    line-height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    top: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
}
```

And the left link with:

```
.header a{
    float: left;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Update: actually you need position: absolute to set the title right on center

Answer (score 2):

You can also set them to inline-block rather than floats.

Two block elements next to each other in the DOM will then flow the same as two words next to each other.  This has the added benefit of stretching the height of the containing elements to the height of the children without worrying about clearing floats or setting overflows.  One caveat is that the DOM element tags have to appear right next to each other, no space between, so that they do not have spacing issues

```
<aside>...</aside><!-- no spaces here --><article>...</article>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cVJBW/

Answer (score 1):

assuming you are looking to do something that resembles a mobile nav, try positioning your link at absolute 0 top and left, and your title absolute top 0 and right and left equal values that is atleast greater than the width of the back link.

```
<div class="header">
   <a class="back-link" href= "#"><i class="fa fa-angle-left icon-white arrow"></i> Left Side Text </a>
   <p class = "header title">Title Text</p>
</div>

.header .title {
    text-align:center;
    position:absolute;
    left:200px;
    right:200px;
    margin:0;
 }
.back-link{
      position:absolute;
      left:0;
 }
```

you can take a look at the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/P2n4G/

Answer (score 1):

look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mLP82/

```
<div class="header">
<div class="titleContainer">TitleText</div>
<div class="linkContainer">Link</div>
</div>
```

and CSS

```
.header {
height: auto;
line-height: 50px;
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
font-size: 12px;
text-align: left;
padding-left: 50px;
}

.titleContainer {
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
font-size: 24px;    
position: absolute;
border: 1px solid red;
}

.linkContainer {
position: relative;
left: 10px;
top: 10px;
border: 1px solid green;
width: 50px;
height: 20px;
line-height: 20px;
padding: 0;
}
```

I change a little your code
Hope this help you!